# Can I leave my Raspberry Pi turned on all the time?

Tags: power-supply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it suitable for running continuously, 24/7?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/325/is-it-suitable-for-running-continuously-24-7)

I want to maximize the life of my Raspberry Pi, should I try to turn it off when I can or is it ok to just leave it running all the time?