# How to know if you're writing on your SD Card?

Tags: sd-card, readwrite

I've read (here: [Is the Raspberry Pi suitable for running continuously, 24/7?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/325/is-the-raspberry-pi-suitable-for-running-continuously-24-7/1276)) that using a Raspberry Pi 24/7 is possible as long as you don't write too much on the SD card. So, how do you know if your system/application writes on it ? Are there kind of log of this ?

To be more precise, in my case I'm using the Raspberry as a DSP and I guess I'm not writing anything on it but, how to be sure ?

Comment: Yo, dude, I heard you like logs! So, I wrote logs about writing your logs!!

Comment: Haha ! I got it. I'm french ;) We love plural wordS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are no longer talking about logs in particular.

Have a look at `/proc/diskstats`.  If you `cat /proc/diskstats` you will see statistics for various devices.

Each device has 11 entries as follows.

```
Name            units         description
----            -----         -----------
read I/Os       requests      number of read I/Os processed
read merges     requests      number of read I/Os merged with in-queue I/O
read sectors    sectors       number of sectors read
read ticks      milliseconds  total wait time for read requests
write I/Os      requests      number of write I/Os processed
write merges    requests      number of write I/Os merged with in-queue I/O
write sectors   sectors       number of sectors written
write ticks     milliseconds  total wait time for write requests
in_flight       requests      number of I/Os currently in flight
io_ticks        milliseconds  total time this block device has been active
time_in_queue   milliseconds  total wait time for all requests
```

See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/stat.txt for further detail.

Comment: That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are logs, most should be under `/var/log`.

Use the command `ls /var/log -lrt` to get a reverse time ordered list of files in that directory.

You can tune some logging with the file `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.  If you want to disable as much logging as possible add a line with `*.*     ~` just after the `#### RULES ####` comment block.

Not all logging may be controlled in this fashion.  Some programs bypass this configuration file and have their own configuration file for logging.

Comment: Thanks! So, you mean I can disable log to prevent a few writes. But is there a way to control if the app I'm running is writing things on the SD card to work ?

Comment: If you run an app which writes to a file wouldn't you want that output?  If you don't want the output perhaps get the app to write to a file on a RAM disc.  That won't impose any wear on the SD card.

Comment: Relevant: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84905/25985

Comment: I don't know if the app is writing on the SD card. I'm looking for a way to detect if the app writes things on the SD card.Managing log's writes is another point.

Answer (score 0):

You could use my [Nard SDK](http://www.arbetsmyra.dyndns.org/nard/) as a platform base. It doesn't use the SD card at all after bootup. One can even remove the SD card and the system will continue to operate just fine.
http://www.arbetsmyra.dyndns.org/nard

Comment: This looks really interesting... Will I be able to run any Raspbian binary within the Raspbian emulator or is it limited ?

Comment: All console based Raspbian Wheezy binaries should work. Avoid applications depending on a GUI and X-Windows though. There is a list at the website with tested examples applications.

Comment: Okay, I'll may give it a try so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Raspbian that can be read only on demand, there is a special blackout-proof flavor of Raspbian called **IPE – Industrial Perennial Environment R1**. http://nutcom.hu/ipe-r1