# Can I create a web hosting for my website on raspberry pi and let it run 24/7

Tags: web-server

I had seen a post in which it was taught how to create your own hosting/server on your computer (but the problem is... You got to keep it running all the time.. It shuts down and the website is down). So I was thinking that considering the money factor Pi can be a great server. 
P.S. : Not much knowledge about server and all. But still I did understand the working at a very amateur level.

Comment: related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/325/is-the-raspberry-pi-suitable-for-running-continuously-24-7

Answer (score 2):

You can run `sudo apt-get install apache2` on your pi to install [Apache2 Webserver](http://httpd.apache.org/). This will install to `/var/www` by default where you can change the files. The web server will automatically start on boot. Also, if running this on a home network, you'll need to [portforward](http://portforward.com/english/applications/port_forwarding/Apache/default.htm) your router. For more information and how to install apache2, check out [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/apache.md). Also, start the webserver with `sudo service apache2 start`, stop the webserver with `sudo service apache2 stop`, and restart the webserver with `sudo service apache2 restart`.