# How can I reduce the writing to log files

Tags: sd-card, logfiles

A common worry of Raspberry Pi users is the [wearing out and destruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24356909/2235831) of their SD card (which have limited write cycles) by too many writes. The experience reported by users supports this assumption.

Logging is one source of frequent write access.

So the question arises how this can be reduced on Raspbian.

Comment: You can move the location of the log files to an external drive or flash drive, but IMO these concerns are overblown.

Comment: *"The experience reported by users supports this assumption."* -> **Only if they are devoid of reason.**  The internet is full of hysterical reports by hysterical people. Bigfoot! UFOs! Logging destroyed my SD card! Etc.  Please see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84905/25985

Comment: Of more concern to me, as someone who often pulls the plug, is to know nothing will be writing to the SD card when I yank the cord.

Comment: @SteveRobillard @goldilocks More than to much writes, is the unexpected power loss; this may not be the sd damage culpit but, just in case, I always do a `shutdown now` and no more SD corruptions.

Comment: @goldilocks I am skeptical with your calculation. It looks quite optimistic. Take a look at [this detailed one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24360304/2235831). >'This way logging every 10 minutes [...]  it will be good for 20 000 years... The calculation above assumes perfect wear levelling and a very efficient file system.' (which is not the case) 'Of course, this can be spoiled quite easily', for example if the card is full, etc. Then the degradation can be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: I agree it's hyperbolic -- but I think that is explicit.  That screed is an antitoxin. The point is the *vast majority* of users do not need to worry about this. People should not consider it fine and normal to operate with a completely filled root filesystem on a pi, their laptop, an inet server, etc; by default ext fs' set aside 5% for root use only to help mitigate against that.  So really you are talking about **corner cases**, and the beef I have here is that you've presented it as if it should be considered an issue by every self-aware citizen.  *No, it should not.*

Comment: It depends on the application.  For instance, I use a Pi with Apache and PHP to do machine control and testing.  The onboard browser constantly refreshes the display page with status (counters, temperature, etc.) which is done through ajax calls to PHP programs.  Each refresh adds a line to the access.log file.  Depending on the refresh rate, this can be a LOT of writes. And the device is on constantly.

Comment: I found mine in this location /home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi/

I ran this commend to narrow it down **sudo du -xh / | grep -P "G\t"**

The result showed *110gb    /home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi/* 
then I did ls -al 

pi@ohrpi01:~ $ ls -al /home/pi/.cache/lxsession/LXDE-pi/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi  4096 Jan  5 02:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi pi  4096 Jan  5 02:10 ..
-rw------- 1 pi pi 105876192832 Jan  5 02:13 run.log <- it looked similar to this. Just wanted to let everyone know where I found mine.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## My solution for Raspbian 8.0 (Jessie) based on logging to RAM

There already exists the [Ramlog Debian package](http://www.tremende.com/ramlog/) and [installation instructions](http://www.lexxi.at/2013/11/29/so-lebt-mein-raspberry-langer/) for this. However, this didn't work for me (Starting ramlog-tmpfs 2.0.0: Error: /var/log is in use... [fail]).

Using `iotop -bktoqqq` I figured out most frequent write access. It turns out that also /var/cache/samba/ is frequently written to. So this also has to go to RAM in addition to /var/tmp/ where the new log files will be.

#### 1. Creating the ramdisk

So first these two entry have to be added to
`/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs           /var/tmp        tmpfs   size=10M,nodev,nosuid     0       0
tmpfs           /var/cache/samba tmpfs   size=5M,nodev,nosuid     0       0
```

#### 2. The log2disk script

We need to save this script in `/usr/local/bin/log2disk` which will append and delete the contents from all log files in `/var/tmp/log/` to the files in `/var/log/`.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Author: Frank Breitling <frank.breitling@gmx.de>
DESC="Moving contents from /var/tmp/log/ to /var/log/"

if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]
then echo "Please run as root"
     exit
fi

echo $DESC

exec >>/var/log/log2disk.log 2>&1

date
cd /var/tmp/

for i in log/*; do
    basename $i
    cat $i >>/var/$i
    >$i
done
```

and make it executable `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/log2disk`.

#### 3. Adding to crontab

We want to run this script every 3 hours and add this line to the system's `/etc/crontab`

```
10 */3  * * *   root    /usr/local/bin/log2disk
```

(Don't forget a final newline which is needed by crontab.)

#### 4. Installing the log2disk.service

We need to create a systemd service in `/lib/systemd/system/log2disk.service` that executes this script before shutdown and reboot, so that the log file contents gets preserved:

```
[Unit]
Description=Write log files to disk
RequiresMountsFor=/
Before=rsyslog.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/log2disk

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and install it with `sudo systemctl enable log2disk`.

#### 5. Selecting the log files for RAM

Now we can tell `/etc/rsyslog.conf` which logfiles to keep in RAM. These files are `auth.log, syslog, daemon.log, user.log and messages` and we replace for each of their entries the `log/` path by `tmp/log/` for example like this:

```
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/tmp/log/auth.log
```

#### Done!

After a reboot, the system will now log the most frequent log entries to `/var/tmp/log` and sync them back every 3 hours and before shut down.

We can use `iotop` again to find a significantly reduced write activity.
However we should not be worried about the [green ACT LED flashing](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/61889/58211). Apparently this is not a good write access indicator.

Comment: *"I have worked out the following solution for Raspbian 8.0 (Jessie) based on the idea of logging to ram."* -> Seeing as how Jessie is systemd based, it is already a few tweaked config lines away from that via journald.  Have a look at `man journald.conf` and note `Storage=volatile`, etc.  Then just plain *disable* rsyslog (it's fed from journald now anyway) and presto, RAM based logging with lots of bells and whistles and customization options.  Without any fuss.

Comment: @goldilocks I wonder how this could be useful for creating such a log file buffer that I have created.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  TBH I'm not a fan of journald (mostly because of the binary format), and the reason I know this much about it is this is what I do with it -- disable logging to disk (and leave that to rsyslog), and give it a modest amount of RAM to use as a buffer.   If you mean periodically flush it to disk, I don't see why not.

Comment: @goldilocks Then how?

Comment: If you've never used it, you should have a look at `man journalctl`.  Like I said I'm an old fashioned syslog guy, but I notice there's a `-s --since` switch; then you just have to get it to dump it in a way appropriate to redirection to a file (that may not happen by default...if you play around a bit you'll get the picture).

Comment: @goldilocks This sounds quite vague and to be honest I have no idea what you are talking about. But usually it turns out that things are not as simple as you think.

Answer (score 15):

If you are not interested in the logs you can switch a lot off using a log configuration setting.

Edit the file `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and just after the section starting

```
###############
#### RULES ####
###############
```

add the following line.

```
*.*     ~
```

If you want to be more fine-grained you will need to read the file comments.

Do not forget to restart rsyslog daemon:

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Comment: Easy and clean solution. I commented everything which writes in /var/ out. It *should* work.

Comment: But I am interested in the logs. They are very important for finding problems of the system!

Comment: If you're interested in logs, there's lots of approaches to retain them, yet avoid SD writes.  Send the logs to /dev/shm (RAM), then run logrotate every 300s, and send the logs to Amazon S3. Or Dropbox. Remember, logs have LIMITED value which is diminished over time. You often only really need timely, current logs...

Answer (score 2):

The way I circumvent this is by installing my root directory to a USB instead of the SD card. I use the SD card only for boot.

This kind of saves me having to worry about writes to my SD Card.

I use berryboot to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than editing rsyslog.conf you can simply stop the service if you want to eliminate all logs.

```
sudo service rsyslog stop
```

Then, you can disable it at boot:

```
sudo systemctl disable rsyslog
```

to enable it again at boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable rsyslog
```

Originally from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32553762

Comment: But that stops all logging.

Comment: You forgot to prefix the commands with `sudo`. If you use `systemctl` you should also use it to stop a service with `sudo systemctl stop rsyslog.service`.

Comment: Very good feedback.  I updated this answer to reflect both of these comments.

Comment: BTW if you copy someone else's answer it's usually polite to reference it. Here, I'll do that for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32553762/4453048

Answer (score 0):

To reduce logfile write operations on the RPi you could set up a centralized log server with rsyslog. If you want to keep the entries, just send the messages to the remote log server, else to /dev/null.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the logging and move it to USB drive.
Good SanDisk 64GB or 128GB USB flash drive is nowadays cheap.

I have many Odroid XU4, Odroid C2, Raspberry Pi B+, and they all log to 64GB SanDisk USB 3.0 drives. It has plenty of space and I notice no performance issues!

I even run a web server on Odroid XU4 with 1TB Samsung USB SSD. OS is on eMMC.

Here's how you do it:

**1. Stop rsyslog**

```
sudo service rsyslog stop
```

**2. Stop Apache**

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

**3.** Stop any other service that may be running and logging to **/var/log/**.

**4.** Unmount any mounted points to /var/log/ (you will remount later).
For example on Armbian I have zram0 partition mounted to /var/log/ (/dev/zram0)

**5.** Backup any needed logs from /var/log/
Create desired log location and mount.

```
# Create the new log directory on the USB drive. In my case mounted as /logs/
mkdir -p /logs/var/log
cp -r /var/log/* /logs/var/log

# Remove the log directory
rm -rf /var/log/
# Create a symlink to the new location
ln -s /logs/var/log /var/log

# Start the services
sudo service rsyslog start
sudo service apache2 start

# Mount any unmounted /var/log/ partition(s), if unmounted!
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /your/location

# Force logrotate retest after you move the log file.
# This will clear "Excess permissions or bad ownership on file /var/log/btmp" error message.
sudo logrotate -v -f /etc/logrotate.conf
```

List the /logs/var/log/ directory
ls -la /logs/var/log/

You may notice some logs or directories missing.
When you restart all services you will see all previous services logging there.

Reboot!

This will restart all services and you will see all active logs in the /logs/var/log/ directory.
If you decide not to move your existing /var/log/ logs, after the reboot all logs will be recreated at the new location.

I've been using SanDisk 64GB Ultra USB 3.0 Flash Drive ($10 an Amazon right now).
Never in my 6 years use I had any of them fail.