# How can I use a USB HDD to extend the life of my SD Card?

Tags: sd-card, performance, hard-drive

How can I set up a USB HDD to extend the life of my SD Card and maximize the performance of my Raspberry Pi?

> Related: [How can I extend the life of my SD card?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/169/46)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're going to have a HDD that's always attached to the Pi, then you can mount the sections of your filesystem that incur the largest number of read/writes directly from it.

These directories are probably the culprits:

```
/home/
/var/
/tmp/
```

You are able to mount partitions on your external hard drive to these directories automatically at boot. Let's say your HDD is `/dev/sdb`, and it has four partitions. You can append your `/etc/fstab` to look something like this:

```
/dev/sdb1       /var        ext4   defaults    0  1
/dev/sdb2       /home       ext4   defaults    0  1
/dev/sdb3       /tmp        ext4   defaults    0  1
/dev/sdb4       none        swap   sw          0  0
```

I've also included a swap partition. Though you might want to research how effective swap can be over USB. I really wouldn't expect much from it.

More information about swap in this question: [How to set up swap space?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70/how-to-set-up-swap-space)

Comment: Would you add a swap partition/file to the HDD (assuming it was not an SSD) and if so how?

Comment: I probably wouldn't bother with swap. It's not going to be very quick over USB. But by all means try it out. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I wonder if the pi will continue to boot when the USB HDD is disconnected?