# Where is the rest of my sd card?

Tags: sd-card

I'm using a 4GB SD card, formatted from a Windows PC with the Debian image. Here's the output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                  94M     0   94M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                   10M  156K  9.9M   2% /dev
tmpfs                  94M     0   94M   0% /dev/shm
rootfs                1.6G  1.5G     0 100% /
/dev/mmcblk0p1         75M   28M   47M  37% /boot
```

Where's all my extra space? There's about 2GB is missing!

Comment: Maybe they are not assigned to a partition?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's there, but not set up as available space.

You can either [use the remaining space as a separate drive/volume](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/654/112) or [resize the partition to the full 4gb](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/499/1)

Answer (score 3):

Because the image that you flashed to the Pi is only 2GB, that's all the space the root partition can see. Either you can resize the root partition or create a new one with `fdisk`.