# Problems with SD card

Tags: sd-card

Just rec'd rasp pi and it came with a loaded sd card. I am having problems with the composite video and was suggested I edit a file on the first partition. When I looked for the file it was not there. I was able to read the dir in win 7 explorer. I was trying to access the second partition, which I never figured out how, all of sudden it cannot read any of the disk and tells me it needs formatted. I backed up the visible partition. If I format it, will it blow up the invisible partition and just format the the 1st partition. These fresh out of the box systems are confusing...I reseated several times and it started to read again.

Here's a screenshot of the dir.

[image: screenshot of pi dir]

Comment: Without knowing what is supposed to be on the card it is difficult to comment. What did the vendor claim was on the card? DO NOT format (unless you want to download an image and start again). Reboot your Windows system, and list what is on the card and paste into your question. (List in a terminal not Explorer.)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Windows really hates it when removable drives (flash drives and SD cards for example) that have multiple partitions.  See this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/862/where-is-the-rest-of-my-sd-card?rq=1) for some more information on that.

If Windows won't even let you into the first partition now, something has gone wrong. I would suggest reflashing the SD card with NOOBS.  The Raspberry Pi Foundation has a good tutorial on that [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/).  As a part of the installation process, NOOBs should give you the ability to edit the `config.txt` as I gave in my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you have listed looks like a NOOBS card. The official instructions for initial setup are on https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/

The instructions assume you can perform the initial setup. The other answer you got about editing config.txt refers to Raspbian.

The image you posted above is incomplete. You should learn to use terminal and list files. I am unsure what is in the other directories on the SD Card.

I have not used NOOBS for years, but that looks like a complete disk. If you have not configured it there will be no other partitions - NOOBS is designed to use just a single FAT partition.

I assume your real problem is in your other question. Incidentally you should not ask multiple questions. If you cannot read the screen you will have difficulties even getting NOOBS/Raspbian initialised.

You should return to your original question if you need further help.