# Add extra partition in Raspberry pi memory card

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, noobs, partition

I need to add extra partitions in raspberry pi memory card.

I am using 16GB memory card with my Raspberry Pi and need Extra Partition so i can arrange data in memory card and save the backup data in that,

So If memory card gets corrupted or any thing happen with root partition my data will safe in that partition like we all do with our MS Windows System hard-disk.

Kindly help me to Make the partition and access that from raspberry pi.

Comment: related (if not dupe) http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/652/how-do-i-create-and-mount-a-partition-using-the-remainder-of-my-sd-card/654#654

Answer (score 1):

It is not difficult to create partitions using a program like `parted`. There is a GUI version `Gparted`.

This is easy if you have FREE SPACE on the SD card. If you have expanded the partition to use the whole card it is not so easy. You cannot shrink active partitions so this needs to be done on another system.

Storing data on a separate partition on the same SD Card does not actually provide that much security, as any failure is just as likely to corrupt any mounted partition.