# How do I transfer my setup between SD cards?

Tags: sd-card

I started out with a 2GB SD card, but I'm finding this a bit cosy, so I've bought a 16GB card to replace it. With a single Pi, can I transfer all my work between the cards, or do I need to start from scratch?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be able to copy the image, using the same application you flashed it with (or the `dd` command in Linux):

```
dd if=/dev/sdx of=/path/to/image
```

Where `sdx` represents the SD card.

This can then be flashed onto the new SD card just like the original one:

```
dd if=/path/to/image of=/dev/sdx
```

For more information, see this question:

[How do I backup my Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/311/how-do-i-backup-my-raspberry-pi)

And you can see how to increase the size of the image here:

[How can I resize my / (root) partition?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/499/how-can-i-resize-my-root-partition)

Comment: Does this require you to have access to the two cards simultaneously (eg to have a second card reader attached)? If not, I assume the image is stored in RAM until it's written to the new card. So, what happens if the original image is larger than the amount of RAM you have available? Thanks!

Comment: @Ben The image is stored on disk at the path you provide via the `of` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm still missing something here. Does this mean that I need to have both SD cards (i.e. two disks) connected to the pi simultaneously?

Comment: @Ben you can't do this on the Raspberry Pi. You must use a separate machine.

Comment: @Ben Could you not use a USB to SD adapter to hold the target card?

Answer (score 1):

There is an app pre-installed with raspbian that can copy the whole sdcard into a new sdcard through USB. The name of the app is sd card copier. It can be found in accessories.