# How best to clone SD card to larger - have tried dd, but get file system errors?

Tags: sd-card, boot-issues, init

I have a headless raspberry pi running Home Assistant and a bunch of other docker containers. It has been running on a 64GB SD for some time and runs fine, but very occasionally runs out of space due to accumulated downloads or similar.

I bought a new 256 GB EVO card, and am trying to clone the old one to the new.

On a linux laptop with SD reader, I did

`sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M of=pi-image.img`

then switch the SD card in the reader to the new one and did

`sudo dd if=pi-image.img bs=1M of=/dev/sda`

When I insert the new card into the pi and power it on, I get a mass of messages, the final one of which is:

`not syncing : no working init found. Try passing init option to kernel. see Linux documentation for guidance`

I checked the `cmdline.txt` file, and blkid for the root partition and they matched

I then tried `e2fsck` on the new SD card, and there was a mass of errors on the rootfs that I tried fixing, but after re-inserting in the pi still the same errors.

I then tried:

- `e2fsck` on the original SD, no errors
- formatted the new SD to a single, full size ext4 partition and ran `e2fsck` - no errors

So given there are no errors in the first part of the process, how can I clone the original 64GB SD to the new 256GB SD without resulting in errors?

Comment: Consider piclone_cmd  which is a command line version of piclone that you can run from the command line on your headless device

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/copy-current-sd-image-to-larger-sd-card/108628#108628

Comment: See [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120124/how-to-copy-sd-card-whithout-copying-the-unallocated-space/120154#120154).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `dd` to write SD cards, you're wasting time, and using the wrong tool for the job. But please don't take my word for it - [check other opinions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12538/286615), or do your own research.

I would suggest you approach this as follows:

1. make an image-backup of your current SD card using `image-backup`. [@user68186 has referenced a link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120124/how-to-copy-sd-card-whithout-copying-the-unallocated-space/120154#120154) that will walk you through the details.

   At the end of this process (which isn't long), you will have an **.img** file that contains an exact replica of every file and smidgen of data on your SD card.
2. With that **.img** file, get a tool like [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) to write your **.img** to your new SD card. Really - these tools make it very easy.

Comment: For the second step, [RPi Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/) should also work. The other thing to note is when you boot from the new 256 GB SD card for the first time, the OS will automagically expand the system partition `/` to use all the empty space.

Comment: Thanks for this - I tried using balena etcher, and the first time it wrote and validated, it said it had failed. So I ran it again and it was successful... so fingers crossed!