# How do I expand a raw disk image?

Tags: setup, storage

The official images supplied are raw disk images, which could have been created using `dd`.

How do I make an image bigger? I'm not interested in repartitioning said image as that has already been answered in [How can I resize my / (root) partition?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/499/86).

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by expanding. Are you looking to perform the 'resizing of the partition' on the image _before_ dd'ing it to the disk?

Comment: That is one goal, but in order to do that, one must expand the disk image.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As explained in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/343705/how-do-i-append-a-specific-number-of-null-bytes-to-a-file) there are two methods of expanding the image. Below are two examples to expand the file by 1 kilobyte.

DD creates a non-sparse file

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1k count=1 >> myimage.img
```

Truncate creates a sparse file

```
truncate -s +1024 myimage
```

You probably want to use truncate. A sparse file only writes the metadata of the blocks it uses, instead of actually writing the blocks. This makes creating the file faster (as it does not have to write actual zero's to the disk) and it saves space on your disk.

> *Note* Apple's HFS+ filesystem does not support sparse files.

Comment: HFS+ doesn't conform to POSIX? http://linux.die.net/man/2/truncate

Comment: If supporting sparse files is a requirement for POSIX i guess not. Here is a nice demonstration of the differences between HFS+ and some ext (i guess) http://stackoverflow.com/a/193015/689893. Appearently it does creates the file but it uses disk space like it's a normal file instead of a sparse file.

Comment: No, I think I had misunderstood!

Comment: If you `dd` a *sparse* file, will it still be right?

Comment: A sparse file does contain data, so i guess you can just add zeroes. It will handle that part as non-sparse.

Answer (score 11):

An incredibly easy way of resizing the image is to use one of the `qemu` tools called `qemu-img`. This of course depends on the fact that you have `qemu` installed (which I know you already do Alex).

The command looks like this:

```
qemu-img resize filename [+|-]size[K|M|G|T]
```

Where `filename` is the image file, and size is the size you want to enlarge (or shrink) the image.

For example, if you want to extend the image `archarm.img` by 2GB you would execute:

```
qemu-img resize archarm.img +2G
```

Comment: Refering to manpage, Before using this command to shrink a disk image, you MUST use file system and partitioning tools inside the VM to reduce allocated file systems and partition sizes accordingly. Failure to do so will result in data loss!