# Resizing a SD card with NOOBS installed

Tags: sd-card

I am having massive problems with moving my system to a bigger card (8GB -> 32 GB). raspi-config extending filesystem doesn't work with NOOBS, I tried gparted where I couldn't re-size my partition due to an unused (2mb) space attached to it.

doing it manually gives me an error when I perform a write operation at the end of the process. After a reboot the system boots to the installation screen - so I assume something goes wrong there. Is there any way to re-size the SD card with NOOBS installed on it ?

Comment: Paste the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0` into your question

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to resize after installation, NOOBS or not.

Sounds like a problem with a not properly formatted SD card.
Have you checked this [discussion](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=57951) on the raspberry.org forum?
Look for the post from jojanonone.

Basically it boils down to this: you *really* need to safe-eject the SD card after formatting or writing to it.

Comment: The SD card is formatted properly and safely removed. After resizing operation I have this error:                                                                                                            WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy. <--------
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8). And after reboot system is corrupted and I have a prompt to install it again.

Comment: What steps are you performing to resize?

Comment: I use this guide : http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/499/how-can-i-resize-my-root-partition

Comment: Okay, that guide assumes that you start with a Raspbian installation, not NOOBS.

Comment: It is much more complicated with NOOBS than suggested by that thread. Take a look at [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=64892) thread in the raspberry.org forum, but I'm not sure it will help you. Also consult [the partitioning info for NOOBS](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/wiki/NOOBS-partitioning-explained). Is there a particular reason to use NOOBS? If you already know you want to run Raspbian, why not go for that directly?

Comment: Also, the guide you where using does not tell you that you need to unmount the  partitions you want to resize, which is crucial. My guess is that this is what led you to the "error 16" message.

Comment: I had Noobs preinstalled on my sd card and have quite few bits configured in it already hence I don't want to start fresh Raspbian installation if I don't have too. Will have look at the the thread you mentioned in your post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually whether NOOBS is present or not shouldn't be an issue with moving the system to a larger SD card and expanding the Raspbian root partition, since (at least with recent NOOBS installs of Raspbian) that's normally the last partition. We'd need to see @zebik 's partition table to start to understand what's really going on here.

Comment: Are you using GPARTED on another Linux device to resize the partition? I'd skip Noobs and move on to just a standalone system. Not sure if piclone (SD card copier)  would work from Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

To move what you have to a bigger sd card you can use [How can I backup my whole SD to an img file usable with Etcher to restore later?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66556/how-can-i-backup-my-whole-sd-to-an-img-file-usable-with-etcher-to-restore-later/66991#66991) as a guide. Using `fdisk` adjust the size for the partitions using the plus number instead of actual last sector number (ie `+63M` for boot and may be `+12G` for Raspbian). Use the `p` subcommand to get the last sector number and add 1 for the next start sector number.