# How can I use fdisk in a bash script?

Tags: pi-2, osmc, bash

Hi guys i follow this [How can I resize my / (root) partition?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/499/how-can-i-resize-my-root-partition) and work .

But it's possible to make an automate bash script?

I have to pass 501760 when ask for start number.

Thank you

Comment: not in the scope of this SE?

Comment: Have you tried the utility `parted`?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer in the sense of "here I wrote a script for you" but it does contain some information that might be helpful to you or someone else who wants to do so.

You can probably automate `fdisk` via a tool called `expect`, which is intended to be used in scripts with interactive CLI tools; the basic idea is you tell `expect` what prompt to expect and what answer to provide using an "expect script".  It isn't installed by default most places, and depends on Tcl, which may also not be installed, so you could just do that and have a look at it and play around, or have a look at the man page online [(e.g.)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) and whatever tutorials and examples you can find (remember, search "linux expect tutorial", do not include "raspberry pi" in your search terms).

*[Regarding OSMC: I'm not sure OSMC is intended to provide things like this, so you should check that first and if `expect` isn't available, keep reading, because it is more likely to have `sfdisk`, which is a better option anyway; if that isn't available give, you are out of luck.]*

Using `expect` is not the ideal answer here, however.  The better option is a tool called `sfdisk` which is sort of like `fdisk`, but intended for scripting using its own format.  This can be fed via stdin, so you could do it with a "here document" in a bash script.

A thing about partition tables is you can screw around with them without destroying any data *as long as you don't actually mount and use any of the partitions*.  The partition table information is written to a part of the device that is separate from the partitions themselves, so you can completely change things, then put it back the way it was -- no harm done.  I'm saying this because you could get comfortable with `sfdisk` by reading the man page and playing around with a spare USB stick (if available).  The first thing you'll want to do is make a back-up copy of the existing table that `sfdisk` can then use to restore things later; see the `-d` option.

Sfdisk is probably installed by default; try `man sfdisk` to find out. You want to read that page anyway.

There is a newer version of `sfdisk` (2.26, from 2015) that has a much better man page (and some additional functionality for GPT disks, but that is irrelevant on the pi).  *Unfortunately*, Raspbian and other Debian derived distros (I think this includes OSMC) are still using a version from 2011.  I would guess it is otherwise much the same but the man page is not as friendly.  The ones found online are mostly for this old version as well.   :( The newer one has a whole section "BACKING UP THE PARTITION TABLE" based on using

```
sfdisk -d /dev/whatever > backup.file
```

That you can later use to restore it if need be using:

```
sfdisk /dev/whatever < backup.file
```

This should be applicable to the old version, just it is not spelled out in the man page.  Note I do not know how agreeable `sfdisk` is to making changes to a mounted partition containing the root filesystem but if you can do it with `fdisk` you can probably do it with `sfdisk`, and it can't hurt to try (unless it actually works and you screw up, lol).

I said earlier that you can do this without harming anything as long as you don't mount and access the partitions but that is not quite true: It's as long as you don't *change* anything.  So you could mount them read-only, or just check it and don't change anything.  In the case of expanding a filesystem, this means:

- Using sfdisk to script expanding the partition.
- Mounting the partition to check the filesystem is still readable. It won't have changed size; to do that you still have to use `resizefs` as per the link in your question (s/fdisk just increases the size of the *partition* so there is room for a bigger *filesystem*), but you want to make sure it is still readable because you want the starting offset the same.  Otherwise I think using `resizefs` will fail and/or wreck the data on the fs.

  You could try to do this by just sticking/keeping it in the pi and seeing if it works but I advise against that unless you are determined to do all this from the pi itself, in which case I'd still look around for that old USB stick to play with first.  And remember, if it *doesn't* work, you are now stuck having to take the card out and fix it elsewhere anyway.
- Using `resizefs` to expand the filesystem on the partition.  If you are trying to do this on a running pi several reboots are needed so you can't really do it with one simple script.  You could do it with one more complicated script set up to fly via init as per `raspi-config`; if you think you are up to that, have a look at how that is done ;)

That's all you need to know to write a script to resize a filesystem.  IMO very few people really need to do that, and the ones that do should have the ability to read and make use of this information.  If it seems beyond your current skills, you probably do not need to be doing this in the first place.

Note that new versions of Raspbian look to have a [new GUI tool](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/page/3/?fish#another-update-raspbian) for expanding the root fs, but of course you are not using Raspbian.

Comment: whit OSMC work this

run sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0

Then press the keys in order:

**d 2** to delete,
**n p 2 Enter Enter** to re-create.
Verify the prompts to make sure what you are entering is sensible. In particular make sure the same starting sector as the one you just deleted.

Reboot and enter:-

sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2

i need to insert start number is 501760 in automatic :)

Comment: Right, so either you get the idea from the above here or you don't.  If you don't, forget about doing it automatically.  Not everyone can replace a head gasket in 90 minutes but then, people who cannot may have to accept setting aside a weekend instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the latest `OSMC` (I run `Kodi` under Raspbian) but AFAIK it has a simple 2 partition FS and has the normal Linux tools.

If so the following should work:-

To resize:-

run `sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0`

Then press the keys in order:

```
**d 2** to delete,
**n p 2 Enter Enter** to re-create.
```

Verify the prompts to make sure what you are entering is sensible.
In particular make sure **the same starting sector** as the one you just deleted.

**Reboot** and enter:-

`sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2`

You could make a script BUT scripting `fdisk` is far from straightforward and you will probably never need to repeat.

Comment: This is really an abbreviated duplicate of the answer the OP links in the question, but I do agree that s/he is better off sticking with that anyway. ;)

Comment: Yes it's the same answer :) when when digit n p 2 ask for start number and my start number is 501760 
i request if it's possible to automate this

Comment: @robello84 just press `Enter` twice to accept the default. Yes it is possible to script (I have done this- usually when I want to move things) BUT it is complex and error prone.