# Unallocated space when writing img files for RPI

Tags: sd-card, partition, storage

Keep in mind I used several micro SD cards and SD card and a USB pin-drive hoping to get a different result, also tried on 3 different computers 2 Windows 10 Home, and a Windows 7 Pro.

I'm trying to write a os(ParrotSec) on to my Raspberry Pi 3 via micro SD card. but every time I do it. I get this:

Photo https://gyazo.com/a6e94016863870c791e4d365be95b3d1

It's a 32 GB micro SD card and it's showing 63mb as its max but I figured out on how to fix that using diskpart.
cmd

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk 1
list partition
clean
list partition
create partition primary
list partition
format fs=fat32 quick
list partition
exit
```

But when I write again it gives me the same results. I also used different img writing softwares like rosa, win32 and rufus.

Extra information.
-operating systems i tried to install
Raspbain and Parrot(parrotsec.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because there are two disk partitions. Only the first can be seen by windows. Once you put the card into your Pi you can expand the filesystem. Raspbian will do this automatically on first boot. I am not familair with Parrot, but instructions for expanding the root file system can be found in this related [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/499/how-can-i-resize-my-root-partition/501#501). You can verify the size of the partitions on your SD card with the following command:

`df -h`.

Comment: i tried pluging in the card in to the raspberry pi, and once i power it up everything runs like it should(The booting aspect) then it goes all black with  a   _   blinking. i sat for 6 mins and nothing happened the operating system is parrot os. the raspberry pi one

Comment: I would suggest you burn Raspbian to your SD card to rule it out as the source of the problem. Note that you should avoid asking a second question in the comments of your first. If you need to ask about a booting issue ask a new question.