# How can I resize my Parrot OS / (root) partition?

Tags: sd-card, partition, storage

I'm using Parrot OS (parrotsec.org).

How can I resize the image so that I have more space on my root partition?

Raspbian does this automatically on boot up, but Parrot OS doesn't. How would I do this?

Comment: you can probably try my answer to this question http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/499/how-can-i-resize-my-root-partition/501#501.

Comment: heres the problem with that, THEY want me to put a cmd in. I CANT TYPE ANY THING it wont boot up. it would run logs like default and then go black with a _ blinking. @SteveRobillard

Comment: You need a bootable system before worrying about expanding the file system

Comment: Bootable system ??!!!. @SteveRobillard

Comment: a system that allows you to run commands, not just a _blinking

Comment: were would i find that or get @SteveRobillard

Comment: You will need to try reimaging the SD card or try another card. Like I mentioned in the previous question starting with Raspbian may be easier - especially if you are new to the Raspberry Pi and Linux.

Comment: i used 2 micro sd cards and a normal sd card same thing. but i just did the raspbian and it resized it and stuff and then booted up with the login info. i removed it and stuffed it into my pc it said theres a problem with the sd card so i used diskpart to clean the partitions  and create a primary partition and formated it. and it fixed it. would i just write my parrot os and it should work now .?? @SteveRobillard

Comment: You can try it. What you did learn is that the Card is not the problem. This would suggest that the download is corrupt. Did you check the download with a hash (most downloads will include a hash value that you can use to check the integrity of the downloaded file).

Comment: it has a folder with txt saying md5sum and sha1, would i use win32 to get the md5 hash and if its the same its fine ? @SteveRobillard

Comment: the md5 hash is the same @SteveRobillard

Answer (score 1):

Problem Found: I tried an older version like Parrot 3.0 and it was working. The 3.4 does not have automatic resizing for the partition.

Comment: The resize shellscript can be copied from raspbian.