# Increasing partition size?

Tags: sd-card, partition

So I'm upgrading from a 4gb card to a 64gb card. I took an image of my (highly configured) 4gb card and I've written it to my 64gb. However, the 64gb card isn't utilizing all its space, there's still 60gb that aren't part of a partition. I created a partition for those missing 60gb and popped the card in my Pi, but it ended up getting stuck in a boot loop.

How can I increase the partition size of the root partition?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/499/how-can-i-resize-my-root-partition/501#501

Comment: I don't know what OS or version you would be using that fits on 4GB. If using a reasonably recent Raspbian `raspi-config` has an option to expand the partition.

Comment: As Milliways says, `raspi-config` is the normal way to do this on Raspbian.  Outside of that context you can use what it does -- `parted` or `fdisk` and `resize2fs`.  That is really a general linux question but you will find oodles of stuff about those specifically here and elsewhere if you look (the duplicate is just one example).