# Why can't I SSH or Real VNC into my RPi4 after expanding the root partition to use the full 32GB sd card?

Tags: sd-card, partition, storage

I was following the solution [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/501/76892) to make full use of my 32GB sd card. After I hit enter to accept the default for the last sector I saw;

```
Created a new partition 2 of type 'Linux' and of size 29.5 GiB.
Partition #2 contains a ext4 signature.

Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o: N
```

I then chose `N` then entered `w` to save. This brought up the following;

```
The partition table has been altered.
Failed to remove partition 4 from system: Device or resource busy
Failed to update system information about partition 2: Device or resource busy

The kernel still uses the old partitions. The new table will be used at the next reboot. 
Syncing disks.
```

I then did a `sudo reboot`

Now I'm unable to connect to my RPi4 over SSH or through Real VNC. They both timeout while trying to connect.

For reference here is a screenshot of the entire process and what my original disk partitions looked like.
[image]

If it helps I created a backup disk image as was suggested [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/311/how-do-i-backup-my-raspberry-pi)

Output from `mount` after reformatting the sd card and reflashing with the backup image.

[image]

Comment: Raspberry Pi OS would have done this automatically on 1st boot, and it can be done manually from raspi-config. I you choose to follow obsolete posts for ancient OS expect problems. It may be possible for an expert to recover, but just restore from your backup.

Comment: **DO NOT** post illegible images of text, post text! It is unclear how you got 4 primary partitions on your SD Card. Without this information the Question is unanswerable.

Comment: @Milliways click the image, it opens in a window and is perfectly legible.

Comment: not on an iPad! If you want help post legible Questions

Comment: @Milliways if you're doing work on an iPad, or any tablet for that matter, you are the exception not the rule.

Comment: Off topic meta discussion is not convincing to provide help for free. I voted to close because "Needs details or clarity".

Answer (score 1):

You really should have stopped following the guide when you saw you had a different number of partitions. The guide above assumes that your root file system is on the second partition. Was that the case? The steps you took made the the data in every partition inaccessible, except the first two, and if your root partition was elsewhere, the system will no longer boot.

You can recover the data by recreating the partition table manually (you have all the numbers you need in your screenshot), or by restoring your backup. In both cases, you will need to plug the SD card into a computer which boots correctly, as the SD card is unbootable until you fix it.

Comment: It was one of the two 3.5G partitions was the root partition but I didn't know how to determine which it was.

Comment: On a working system you can find out which partition is which with `mount`

Comment: I have been able to reformat the disk and flash it with my original image before following the answer I linked to. I booted it up on my RPi4 but the `mount` command doesn't make it real clear to me what is the root and which ones I can safely merge to utilize most of the 32GB disk space. I've updated my question with the `mount` output.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments I think you have overwritten the exiting filesystem.  I would restore the sd card from the backup image.

When you log back in, issue the following commands:

sudo su
raspi-config

In the menu that appears use the arrow keys to move down to selct select item 7 Advanced options.
In the next menu select item A1 Expand Filesystem

That will expand the filesystem to the whole sd card automagically.

Comment: I tried this first but it failed. I forget the exact error at the moment but it basically said it wasn't able to complete the file system expansion.