# How can I install keybase (and dependencies) without running out of memory?

Tags: memory, golang

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 running the most recent Raspbian distro.

I've installed the most recent go, from the prebuilt package and have it on my path:

```
$ go version
go version go1.9 linux/arm
```

However, when I try to install keybase:

```
$ go get github.com/keybase/client/go/keybase
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_arm/link: running gcc failed: fork/exec /usr/bin/gcc: cannot allocate memory
```

I've looked around and tried a few different things, like lowering my ulimit, to no avail. Any clue what I can do to install the most recent version of keybase?

Answer (score 5):

create a swap file with 4 GB of space:
This was my problum when installing docker i had to create a swap file and it worked same error code, so let me know if this works!

## Source: [This Post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1605/74353)

> Raspbian uses dphys-swapfile, which is a swap-file based solution instead of the "standard" swap-partition based solution. It is much easier to change the size of the swap.
>
> The configuration file is:
>
> ```
> /etc/dphys-swapfile
> ```
>
> The content is very simple. By default my Raspbian has 100MB of swap:
>
> ```
> CONF_SWAPSIZE=100
> ```
>
> If you want to change the size, you need to modify the number and restart dphys-swapfile:
>
> ```
> /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile stop
> /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile start
> ```
>
> Edit: On Raspbian the default location is /var/swap, which is (of course) located on the SD card. I think it is a bad idea, so I would like to point out, that the /etc/dphys-swapfile can have the following option too:
>
> ```
> CONF_SWAPFILE=/media/btsync/swapfile
> ```
>
> I only problem with it, the usb storage is automounted, so a potential race here (automount vs. swapon)