# How to install newer cmake on Raspbian?

Tags: software-installation, packages

I have a Raspberry Pi 1B with Raspbian Buster. It comes with cmake 3.13. I need version 3.16 or later. How can I obtain this version of cmake?

What I tried so far:

I attempted to compile cmake from source. Unfortunately, the linker crashes during the linking step. I suspect it is because of an out-of-memory condition. In the end I just see:

```
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
```

I was not not able to find pre-built binaries for this platform and I do not have a newer Raspberry Pi with more memory.

Comment: @goldilocks I don't understand what you mean. I don't see any arm binaries there.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, when I first glanced at this I thought "I attempted to compile..." something else and you thought using 3.16 would make it better.  If you've already tried a source compile, that sucks.

Comment: Just noting that this one does not seem to work on an RPi 1: https://snapcraft.io/install/cmake/raspbian

Answer (score 3):

Set up a [swap](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70/how-to-set-up-swap-space/1605) file / partition and try again. You can get rid of the swap once the compilation is over, but I'd keep it: if you're going to use `cmake` to build more stuff, you'll likely need it again.

Another trick which drastically reduces the linker memory requirements (at the expense of worse performance of the built binaries) is to disable link-time optimization with `-fno-lto`.

Comment: It turns out that it may have been my mistake: I was using `ninja` instead of make, assuming it would be more efficient. It turns out that `ninja` starts two build commands in parallel even on this single-core machine. I made two changes: use `ninja -j1` and compile as `MinSizeRel`. Now it succeeded. I don't know which of the two is responsible for the success, and given the compilation times, I woudn't want to re-run it to find out ... LTO was not enabled.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think you will find out soon enough, once you start using `cmake` to build bigger projects. And yeah, it's pretty normal that `cmake` doesn't use LTO, it's not the kind of software where performance really counts. You'll likely to see this option when building a game or a web browser.