# swap file falls off after reboot when move to USB flash

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, swap-space

I trying move swap file to USB flash from SD card it work fine but after rebooting swap file falls off, command **free -m** show swap is 0

I move swap file to USB flash

1. dphys-swapfile swapoff
2. dphys-swapfile uninstall
3. edit file /etc/dphys-swapfile set variable CONF_SWAPFILE=/media/usb/swap.file
4. dphys-swapfile setup
5. dphys-swapfile swapon

in fstab mount USB flash
UUID=uuid /media/usb ext4 nofail  defaults,  0 0

but after reboot swap file falls

Comment: On Buster dphys-swapfile is broken. It doesn't create a valid swapfile. See https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1933730#p1933730 for details of what you need to change to fix it.

Comment: thanks, i use bulleye, maybe in bulleye dphys-swapfile have some problem too, i solve this problem other way set in file /etc/dphys-swapfile size of swap file 0 and enable swap file [other way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/75/141424)

Answer (score 0):

It could be when your SD card is reaching the end of its life that it is internally switching to readonly mode and that your changes on it (in the /etc/dphys-swapfile) are lost at reboot. It is a common phenomen with SD cards according to here: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=76351

Comment: thanks, but this problem appears only if i have change location swap file from SD card to USB drive, USB drive work fine